# Y axis disappears when I try to use state_smooth() without geom_point()

Tags: r, ggplot2

For some reason, ggplot is omitting the Y axis labels when I try to use stat_smooth() without first calling geom_point(). The hacky solution I came up with was to call geom_point(size = 0, alpha =0), but I'd love (1) to understand what's going on and (2) a more elegant solution.

### Minimal reproducible example

```
library(tidyverse)
# Mock data
set.seed(24)
df <- tibble(x = rep(c(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 13), 20),
  y = round(.3 * x + rnorm(140, 5)),
  z = rep(c("A", "B"), 70))

# Original plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = z)) + 
  geom_point() +
   stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = "y ~ x", se = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 10, length = 4), 
    minor_breaks = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9), 
    labels = c("1. Fully disaproves", "4", "7", 
      "10. Fully approves")) 

# The plot I actually want (except the Y axis labels disappear)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = z)) + 
   stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = "y ~ x", se = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 10, length = 4), 
    minor_breaks = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9), 
    labels = c("1. Fully disaproves", "4", "7", 
      "10. Fully approves")) 

# Hacky solution
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = z)) + 
  geom_point(size = 0, alpha = 0) +
   stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = "y ~ x", se = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 10, length = 4), 
    minor_breaks = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9), 
    labels = c("1. Fully disaproves", "4", "7", 
      "10. Fully approves"))
```

### Output

[image: Original plot]
[image: Plot without geom_point()]
[image: Hacky solution]

PS: I'm totally blind–obviously, I can't see the output. There's a chance that the plots don't show at all what I hope they do. Hopefully, You'll be able to figure out what I want from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you use `stat_smooth` only, the range of the plotted data is different from when you also add the `geom_point`. As by default ggplot2 sets the `limits` of the scale according to the range of the data you get a scale which ranges from 5 to 9. Because of this only one of your breaks (i.e. 7). will show up, while all other breaks are omitted as they fall out of the limits. This said, to achieve your desired result you have to set the `limits`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)
# Mock data
set.seed(24)
df <- tibble(x = rep(c(1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 11, 13), 20),
             y = round(.3 * x + rnorm(140, 5)),
             z = rep(c("A", "B"), 70))

# The plot I actually want (except the Y axis labels disappear)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = z)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = "y ~ x", se = FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 10, length = 4), 
                     minor_breaks = c(2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9), 
                     labels = c("1. Fully disaproves", "4", "7", 
                                "10. Fully approves"),
                     limits = c(1, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: My apologies for forgetting to load the libraries in the Reprex. I'll edit my question accordingly.